# Does set command affect all connections in the same pool?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, dbcontext

I'm using the following statement to adjust the deadlock priority for a specific function:

```
dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY -4");
```

Will this statement affect all contexts with the same connection string or all connections in the same pool?

Comment: And then there is also [MARS (Multiple Active Result Sets)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h32h3abf(v=vs.110).aspx) which introduces statement interleaving and 'preserving historical behavior' (note the copying of SET options back to the default environment under MARS).

Answer (score 1):

The [`SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186736.aspx) as per the MSDN

> Specifies the relative importance that the current session continue
>   processing if it is deadlocked with another session.

That said, the deadlock priority will be set to the scope of the current SQL Connection

Comment: If the current connection is pooled and reused by another process, will the deadlock_priority propagate to that process?

Comment: Good question however I am not sure so this must be tried out